# ASP.NET Attempt to attach auto-named a database failed?

Tags: asp.net

> Parser Error Message: An attempt to
>   attach an auto-named database for file
>   D:\Projects\Damnation\Damnation.Website\Damnation.Website.Tracker\BugNET_WAP\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name
>   exists, or specified file cannot be
>   opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Why could this be happening? My connection string doesn't use `|DataDirectory|`, it is:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="BugNET" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dnmain;Integrated Security=True;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I get this error when I try to load default.aspx, after installing [BugNET](http://bugnetproject.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, and certainly for some obscure reason. There is a mistery connection string coming from... nowhere.

Problem solved adding a `<clear/>` tag.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear/>
  <add name="BugNET" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dnmain;Integrated Security=True;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

> file
>   D:\Projects\Damnation\Damnation.Website\Damnation.Website.Tracker\BugNET_WAP\App_Data**aspnetdb.mdf**
>   failed.

This is the ASP.NET standard membership system here - not your "regular" database. There must be a second connection string somewhere that references this `aspnetdb.mdf` and tries to attach it from a file.

Search your solution for this file name - it must be somewhere!

Comment: I did a text-search (ctrl-shift F) and it found no matches for `aspnetdb.mdf` nor the attach attribute ... it's really weird...